# Not being able to download from S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I know I am being silly, and probably it does not even need to do with S3 syntax (As I got it working if I don't write class, and just as a script)

So here is my code -

```
const logger = require('../../worker/utils/logger');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const config = require('../../config');
const AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket';
const fs = require('fs');

class DownloadContextData {
  constructor() {}
  download(key, filename) {


    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
      region: config.AWS_STORAGE_REGION,
    });
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    try {
      const file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
      s3.getObject({ Bucket: `${AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}`, Key: `${key}` })
        .createReadStream()
        .pipe(file);
    } catch (error) {
      logger.err(e);
    }
  }

  getOjectFileKey(key) {
    return `rec_context/rec_context_${key}000`;
  }


  getListingContext() {
    return this.download(
      this.getOjectFileKey('building'),
      'myfile.txt',
    );
  }
}

module.exports = DownloadContextData;
```

Now, when I do

```
let downLoadContextData = new DownloadContextData();
downLoadContextData. getListingContext();
```

It throws the error,

> 'The authorization header is malformed; the authorization header requires three components: Credential, SignedHeaders, and Signature.'

I know my code and everything else is perfect because I wrote whole thing as a script and it worked. It's just how I am forming/using the class as I am yet not comfortable around Javascript.

Comment: Your JavaScript syntax seems correct. Are you sure about your bucket settings or correct data types in your config file? I tried your code with my configuration and tried to download a file and I have obtained the file. I mean... all your configuration values should be strings.

Comment: Great direction you pointed me in. So I set a key as `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='ABCDEFGHI',`  in `.env` file (Which is, a trailing comma at the end. Seems sorted now.